# Is there a more decentralized RPC server for MetaMask than Infura?

Tags: metamask, infura, rpc, privacy, mainnet

The default RPC server for MetaMask browser extension is Infura. However, Infura is known to monitor the IP addresses and other data of its users.

Anyone who is touting decentralization of crypto, but using MetaMask with this default RPC server, obviously knows nothing about what decentralization really should be.

Is there a 2nd best RPC server in common usage after Infura for accessing Ethereum mainnet that is truly decentralized? What is it?

Comment: Using a provider necessarly requires you to trust them. If you want decentralisation (for you and for everyone else), run your own node.

Answer (score 1):

The most decentralised alternative is that you run your own node.

If you want Infura alternative and do not really care about decentralisation ethereumnodes.com has a list. Most decentralised centralised provider is Pokt Network.

Comment: Could you add to your answer why Pokt Network is the most decentralised node? Do not want malware from visiting external links

Comment: Pokt Network is a centralised relay of RPC providers

Comment: you just said Pokt Network is the most decentralised. Now you say it's centralised?

Comment: Please read my answer. If you have any further questions please open a new question on this website.